# Use Django Auth User for frontent Firebase authentification

Tags: python, reactjs, django, firebase-authentication

I'm using `Django` as my **Backend** REST API with `MongoDB` and `React` in my **Frontend**.

**My goal** is to work with multiple Databases. `MongoDB` *(handled over Django)* and `Firebase` *(mostly handled in Frontend over `React` in JSX)*.

Currently, all my users and authentification is happening in Django with MongoDB and I want to use the already existing working user accounts to log into Firebase in the Frontend if they are logged in in Django. I found multiple resources but nearly all of them have the users and auth happening in Firebase and I need it the opposite way. My users are in Django so I need some kind of creds or auth that will be forwarded to the frontend and logged the user automatically into firebase if they're logged in into Django.
I hope anyone can help me out I'm lost here been reading a lot of resources but none was matching this request.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is known as custom authentication in Firebase, where:

1. Your server-side code authenticates the user.
2. It then mints a Firebase token based on the credentials, for example by using the Firebase Admin SDK for Python.
3. It passes that token to the client over a secure connect, for example as the response to the request that the client made to sign in.
4. The client finally uses the token to sign in to Firebase.

The entire process is best described in the Firebase documentation on [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)